# Por qué? al momento de mandarle los datos del archivo csv al datagrid se me visualiza de esa forma?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Botón que Abre el explorador de windows para seleccionar el archivo con formato csv

```
private void BtnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "(CSV 
    files (*.csv)|*.CSV" };
    var result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == false) return;
    txtRuta.Text = ofd.FileName;
    LLenarGridCsv(txtRuta.Text);
}
```

Con este método quiero pintar la info en el datagrid

```
private void LLenarGridCsv(string archivo)
{

    string path = @"" + archivo;

    List<string[]> lista = new List<string[]>();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string linea;
        int topline = 5;
        int contador = 0;
        while ((linea = sr.ReadLine()) != null && contador <= topline)
        {
            contador += 1;
            string[] partes = linea.Split(',');
            lista.Add(partes);
        }
    }
    DataGridCsv.ItemsSource=lista;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria excelente que tbn dejaras un ejemplo del contenido del archivo csv, de esta forma cualquiera puede tratar de replicar tu inconveniente.